# How to update Localstorage

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have an API endpoint that returns authenticated user data with a list of phone numbers that are saved to local storage and also a component that fetches the phone numbers from the local storage. I want to update the local storage when a phone number is selected by changing the index of the selected phone number to 0. Please how do I achieved this?

My code below.

**Userdata in localstorage**

```
useraccount {        
     accounts: [
          0: {phone: "010475758585"}
    
          1: {phone:"090839494404" }
        ]
    }
```

**Component**

```
     const{useraccount: {accounts}} = isAuthenticated()

     **// Endpoint below is dependent on the selected phone number**


    const getUserTransactions =() =>{
       axios.get(`http://example/transactions/${accounts[0]?.phone}`,{
        headers: {
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
        }
       }).then((res)=>{
         if(res.data){
           console.log(res.data);
           setFetchingTransactions(res.data)
         }else{
           console.log("failed")
         }
       })
    }

  useEffect(() => {
    
      getUserTransactions()
  }, []);

  
      
      return  (
            <>
               <h3>Select an phone</h3>   
                  <ul>
                      {accounts && accounts.map((item, id) => (
                      <li key={id}>
                     <h3>{item.phone}</h3>
                 </li>         
               ))}
          </ul>
          <Button type="submit"  >
                  Select
            </Button>
    </>
    )
```

Comment: *"I want to update the local storage when a phone number is selected by changing the index of the selected phone number to 0"* - It is difficult to understand what you meant by this. Please edit you question and make this clearer.

Answer (score 2):

useHooks has a very useful hook for this called `useLocalStorage`. See https://usehooks.com/useLocalStorage/

you would use it like this

```
 const [transactions, setTransactions] = useLocalStorage('transactions', []);

 useEffect(() => {
     const newTransactions = getUserTransactions();
     setTransactions(newTransactions);
 }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can update your local storage by just setting the value for the key again.
**Like** :
`foo.jsx`

```
    class foo extends React.Component {
        constructor(){
          localStorage.setItem("foo", "foo"); 
        }
    
        updateStorage = (val) => {
           localStorage.setItem("foo", val); 
        }
    
        render(){
            return(
                <div>
                    <button onClick="() => this.updateStorage("foobar")">Update storage</button>
                    <h3>{{ localStorage.getItem("foo") }}</h3>
                </div>
            )
        }
    
    }
```